# java swing layout of two components

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment

```
    +--------------------------------------------+
    |                 +-------+      +----------+|
    |                 | +---+ |      |  +-----+ ||
    |                 | | A | |      |  |  B  | ||
    |                 | +---+ |      |  +-----+ ||
    |                 +-------+      +----------+|
    +--------------------------------------------+
                          ^
                          |
                          |
                        Center
```

Background: **I have**

- a JButton ("A"), size 50x25, within a JPanel (FlowLayout.CENTER)
- a JLabel  ("B"), size 100x25, within a JPanel (FlowLayout.RIGHT)
- the two JPanels are in a JPanel

Desired Result: **I want**

- The JButton "A" to always be centered horizontally,
- The JLabel "B" to always be flush right.

Thing I've tried: **These didn't work for me**

- BorderLayout is not working for me because JButton "A" is shifted LEFT:
- I'd prefer not to put an invisible component WEST to undo the shift

  ```
  +--------------------------------------------+
  |            +-------+           +----------+|
  |            | +---+ |           |  +-----+ ||
  |            | | A | |           |  |  B  | ||
  |            | +---+ |           |  +-----+ ||
  |            +-------+           +----------+|
  +--------------------------------------------+
                   ^    ^
                   |    |
                   |    |
                   |  Center
                   |
                 Shifted Left
  ```
- GridLayout won't work because I don't want the "A" and "B" to be expanded

Appreciate any suggestions!

p.s.

The JButton/JLabels are each inside of their own JPanels because WITHOUT the Jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER expands the JButton across the entire width of the major panel (up to the left edge of the JLabel).  The JPanels are not needed/critical to the statement of the problem

**Conclusion**:

- I went with "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" answer posted below.  Thanks!

Comment: Never set any component size explicitly, this has been repeated a zillion time here!

Comment: Why do you put each of your `JButton` and `JLabel` into their own "private" `JPanel`s, is there a reason for doing so?

Comment: The JButton/JLabels are each inside of their own JPanels because WITHOUT the Jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER expands the JButton across the entire width of the major panel (up to the left edge of the JLabel).  The JPanels are not needed/critical to the statement of the problem

Comment: @jfpoilpret: is there any good way of ensuring that the control's size is exactly 100x25 _without_ setting it explicitly?

Comment: *"I'd prefer not to put an invisible component WEST to undo the shift"*  Why exactly?  It seems designers of GUIs generally spend far more time trying to make a layout work, by not taking the obvious approach.

Comment: Unless the button contains no text, how do you know it is going to be require 100x25 (not less than, & not, more importantly, greater than).  The same goes doubly for a label.

Comment: @Andrew: well, because it's unnatural way. <holiwar mode> In WPF, this is as simple as <Grid><Panel Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/><Panel Width="100" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/></Grid>. You see? </holiwar mode>

Comment: *"You see?"*  No, I don't see that.. on Mac. or *nix, since that stuff targets just one OS.  The point of Java layouts is that they are robust enough to handle different platforms, PLAFs, screen sizes, resolutions..  Oh, and forget the platform layout 'holiwar' - Java is agnostic. ;)

Comment: @Andrew: my point: "Swing's layout management is inferior to WPF's one." Your point: "so what? Java is a better language because it runs on different platforms." How does your point disprove mine?

Comment: @Vlad: I don't know that your statements "prove" that WPF's layouts are *better*, but rather just that they're simpler for this example. Even if they're simpler for all uses, simplicity is just one factor; we have no idea of their power or extensibility.

Comment: @Hovercraft: from my personal experience, the simple layouts can be expressed in WPF in a much easier way than in Swing. So the OP's problem is not an exception but rather a rule. The WPF layout manager is powerful enough: for example, I needed to write a custom layout manager only once in my practice (2,5 years writing WPF controls library for a big commercial project).

Comment: @casio: don't forget to set the tick to the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Your point?  "WPF is a One-liner on the One OS it works on."  A very capable layout in a very limited circumstance.  If you're only developing for One OS, why not use the One layout management system that gives the One liner?  If you want to support more than One OS, let's see how many lines of code it will take in adapting that to *support them.*

Comment: @Andrew: my point is that the All-OS Language ought to keep up with One-OS language in layout management area. That writing All-OS programs in All-OS requires insight and ingenuity in the area where the One-OS developers see no problem at all. That if I need to support not all the desktop OSes (layout management is for desktop, right?), but only the most popular one, I can invest my effort into the functionality and not layout. (I think we are heavily off-topic here, let's move to chat?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should nest JPanels and use a combination of layouts. Placing the panels holding the JButtons into another JPanel that uses GridLayout(1, 0) (1 row, variable number of columns) could work, and placing that JPanel into the BorderLayout.NORTH position of a BorderLayout-using JPanel could work.

For example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo003 {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
      JButton btnB = new JButton("B");

      btnA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
      btnB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

      JPanel btnAPanel = new JPanel(); // uses default FlowLayout.CENTER
      JPanel btnBPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      btnAPanel.add(btnA);
      btnBPanel.add(btnB);

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      topPanel.add(new JLabel("")); // empty placeholder label
      topPanel.add(btnAPanel);
      topPanel.add(btnBPanel);

      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo003");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there _really_ no easier way for such a trivial layout? :(

Comment: 1) It's not trivial, and 2) this is easy.

Comment: +1 for GridLayout and an empty left placeholder. This is exactly what I would've suggested.

Comment: Another option if you don't mind using 3rd party libraries is [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: @Hovercraft: Well, in WPF it's both trivial and easy. I assumed that Swing is not less advanced.

Comment: @Vlad: WPF? Do you mean "Windows Presentation Foundation"? :)

Comment: @Hovercraft: yes, Windows Presentation Foundation, with XAML. Is it somehow heretical to mention it? They have a wonderful layout management system.

Comment: I think many agree that the standard layout managers are not fully "complete", but they are quite extensible which is why there are several good 3rd party additions. Consider using one or two.

Comment: @Hovercraft: having come from WPF, I find inability of Swing layout management to solve trivial layout tasks in a trivial way frustrating. Compare the trivial solution to the OP's problem in WPF with your quite complicated code: <Grid><Panel Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/><Panel Width="100" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/></Grid> Do you still think your way is easy? Do you still think the problem is not trivial?

Comment: @Vlad: I'm not disagreeing with you. Every tool has its relative strengths and weaknesses. I personally like the Swing layout managers, but I know them relatively well and am comfortable quickly whipping up a layout, but again, I'm not saying that their optimal because they're not. But they do work, and again, they are quite extensible.

Comment: Thanks, that was very informative, I've used GridLayout before, but not in the way that you described.   Thanks for all the responses!